# Quick but detailed way to see that $i^\#:\mathcal{O}(\mathbb{A}^2)\to \mathcal{O}(U)$ is an isomorphism?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Consider the affine scheme $\mathbb{A}^2=(Spec \mathbb{C}[x,y],\mathcal{O})$ and the open subscheme $U=(U,\mathcal{O}|_U)$ where $U=Spec \mathbb{C}[x,y]\setminus\{(x,y)\}$. We have a natural inclusion $i:U\hookrightarrow \mathbb{A}^2$ where $i:U\to Spec\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ is just the inclusion and for all open $V\subset Spec\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ we have the map
$$i^\#_V:\mathcal{O}(V)\to (i^*\mathcal{O}\mid_U)(V)=\mathcal{O}\mid_U(i^{-1}(V))=\mathcal{O}(V\cap U)$$
given by the restriction $res_{V,V\cap U}:\mathcal{O}(V)\to \mathcal{O}(V\cap U)$. I want to determine $i^\#(Spec\mathbb{C}[x,y])$, i.e. the map
$$res_{Spec\mathbb{C}[x,y],U}:\mathcal{O}(Spec\mathbb{C}[x,y])\to \mathcal{O}(U)$$
Here is my approach: I know that $\mathcal{O}(U)\cong\mathbb{C}[x,y]$. This isomorphism is realised by noting that by definition of a sheaf $\mathcal{O}(U)$ can be identified with pairs of sections $(a,b)\in \mathcal{O}(D(x))\times \mathcal{O}(D(y))$ such that $a|_{D(xy)}=b|_{D(xy)}$ and this given an isomorphism $\mathcal{O}(U)\cong \mathbb{C}[x,y]\subset \mathcal{O}(D(xy))=\mathbb{C}[x,y,1/x,1/y]$.

In other words, the image of an element $s\in\mathcal{O}(U)$ under this isomorphism $\mathcal{O}(U)\cong\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ is $s|_{D(xy)}$.

So to see that $res_{Spec\mathbb{C}[x,y],U}$ is an isomorphism, we note that $x|_{D(xy)}=x\in \mathbb{C}[x,y]\subset \mathcal{O}(D(xy))$ and similarly for $y$, which proves the claim.

Now I feel like I'm doing way to much work for this. I would appreciate a quicker way of seeing this, that is still precise and uses just the definitions of an affine scheme (so no argument like "a polynomial function on $\mathbb{C}^2\setminus 0$ can be extend to a polynomial function on $\mathbb{C}^2$ or something like that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you are looking for, but this presentation made the proof clearer for me. In particular, it gives a good justification as to why the isomorphism $\mathcal{O}(U) \simeq k[x,y]$ you wrote down is actually the restriction map.

Let $U = \mathbf{A}^2 \smallsetminus \{0\}$, which we can cover by $V_1 = \mathbf{A}^2 \smallsetminus \{x=0\}$ and $V_2 = \mathbf{A}^2 \smallsetminus \{x=0\}$. Let $V_{12} = V_1 \cap V_2$ be their intersection. By the sheaf property, the sequence
$$
  0 \longrightarrow \mathcal{O}(U) \longrightarrow \mathcal{O}(V_1) \times \mathcal{O}(V_2) \longrightarrow \mathcal{O}(V_{12})
$$
is an exact sequence (of abelian groups), where the maps are respectively given by
$$
  f \longmapsto (f\rvert_{V_1},f\rvert_{V_2}) \quad \text{and} \quad (g_1,g_2) \mapsto g_1\rvert_{V_{12}} - g_2\rvert_{V_{12}}.
$$
Since $\mathcal{O}(V_1) = k[x^{\pm1},y]$, $\mathcal{O}(V_2) = k[x,y^{\pm1}]$, and $\mathcal{O}(V_{12}) = k[x^{\pm1},y^{\pm1}]$, we have the commuative diagram
$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}
  0 @>>> k[x,y] @= k[x,y] @>>> 0\\
  @. @VV\rho_{\mathbf{A}^2,U}V @VV(\rho_{\mathbf{A}^2,V_1},\rho_{\mathbf{A}^2,V_2})V @VVV\\
  0 @>>> \mathcal{O}(U) @>>> k[x^{\pm1},y] \times k[x,y^{\pm1}] @>\varphi>> k[x^{\pm1},y^{\pm1}]
\end{CD}$$
where $\rho_{W,Z}$ denotes the restriction of a section from an open set $W$ to an open set $Z$. To show that $\rho_{\mathbf{A}^2,U}$ is an isomorphism, we use the snake lemma. Injectivity follows by injectivity of $(\rho_{\mathbf{A}^2,V_1},\rho_{\mathbf{A}^2,V_2})$. Surjectivity follows by noting that the map $\varphi$ induces an injection of the cokernel of $(\rho_{\mathbf{A}^2,V_1},\rho_{\mathbf{A}^2,V_2})$ into $k[x^{\pm1},y^{\pm1}]$, which follows by the exactness of
$$
  0 \longrightarrow k[x,y] \longrightarrow k[x^{\pm1},y] \times k[x,y^{\pm1}] \longrightarrow k[x^{\pm1},y^{\pm1}],
$$
which you already know. $\blacksquare$

Comment: Yes this is more or less what I was looking for in the sense that it is a proof of the fact that the restriction is an isomorphism. I was hoping for a sort of "one line argument" though, because for some reason I felt that this should  be obvious. It seems that as far as you know there is no such one line argument I guess? So while it is not very difficult, I think many authors should spend some more time writing out these details because most people just skip over this reasoning, pretending that it is immediate that this is an isomorphism

Comment: @user2520938 I don't know what a one line argument means for you, but yes, I at least think that this is as simple as it gets. (There's also the "algebraic Hartogs" proof, but that of course uses more than the definition of an affine scheme.)